# transform in javascript a string containing complex structure in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

everybody.

I have a problem with a string extracted from a text file, that I need to transform in an array.
This is an example of the structure I have to work with:

```
data: '[
            {
              text: "Go",
              name: "search",
              onClick: function () {
                console.log(document.getElementById("searchName").value);
                alert("Value: " + document.getElementById("searchName").value + "button: " + idCaller);
              },
            },
            {
              text: "Cancel",
              name: "btnCancel",
            },
          ]'
```

Checking the string with length, It finds of course an array with around 500 elements...

I tried to look for suggestions on the web, included many answer in *stackoverflow*, but I can't find a correct way.
A line code like this:

```
let array = JSON.parse(data);
```

doesn't work because it doesn't recognize a correct JSON structure.

Another usual way is the use of the split() function, but as it needs a delimiter, and ',' (comma) is incorrect, it doesn't apply.

Has someone a solution or a suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You can do `const result = eval(data)` and you will get something that you want, but there are a lot of drawbacks of using eval function.

One of the most important reasons to avoid eval in most of cases is security (basically you are executing code from the string that can be malicious), there are of course other reasons as well. Basically that code can be anything that javascript can have, so when trying to execute you may fall in problems with `this` object, calling functions that does not exist in running context, etc.

Comment: Exactly, I know eval() function and I don't want to use it. Too dangerous.